# Linq add extra column (max date)

Tags: c#

I have class Student with collections of Exams,each exam has title and date.
In my view model i would like to display a grid with each exam of each student but i would like to add extra column with latest exam date (i know this will be repeated for each line but this is how it was requested.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}

public class Exam
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExamDate { get; set; }
}

public class ExamViewModel
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string ExamTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExamDate { get; set; }
    public Exam LastExam { get; set; }
}
```

In each row i would like to put the Max last exam date

```
var list = (from s in uow.Students.GetAll()
            join e in uow.Exams.GetAll() on s.Id equals e.StudentId
            select new ExamViewModel
            {
                StudentName = s.Name,
                ExamTitle = e.Title,
                ExamDate = e.ExamDate,
                LastExam =???
            });
```

result should be like this

- Name-----------------ExamTitle------Date-----------------LatestExamDate
- Mike Peter --------- French ------- 15/03/2015---------  20/12/2015
- Mike Peter --------- Math---------- 16/03/2015---------  20/12/2015
- Mike Peter --------- UML ---------- 20/12/2015 --------  20/12/2015
- David Ula ---------- C#------------ 12/12/2015 --------  14/12/2015
- David Ula ---------- VB------------ 16/09/2015 --------- 14/12/2015
- David Ula ---------- Bio----------  14/12/2015 --------- 14/12/2015
- David Ula ---------- Mngmt--------- 10/10/2015 --------- 14/12/2015

Comment: Is `LatestExamDate` the lastest exam date for that user, or the latest exam date for all exams?

Comment: LatestExamDate is for the user

Comment: And your property `Exams` - is that properly hooked up as a foreign relationship (I'm assuming this is being converted to SQL?)

Comment: Yes, i'm using EF6 for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a two-way navigation properly to make this query a lot simpler.

Add the following property to `Exam`

```
public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
```

And then configure it to work with your existing `StudentID`.

Your query then becomes:

```
uow.Exams().GetAll().Select(e => new {
    StudentName = e.Student.Name,
    ExamTitle = e.Title,
    ExamDate = e.ExamDate,
    LastExamDate = e.Student.Exams.Max(e => e.ExamDate)
})
```

Alternatively, you'd need to do this:

```
var list = (from s in uow.Students.GetAll()
        join e in uow.Exams.GetAll() on s.Id equals e.StudentId
        select new ExamViewModel
        {
            StudentName = s.Name,
            ExamTitle = e.Title,
            ExamDate = e.ExamDate,
            LastExamDate = uow.Exams.GetAll().Where(e => e.StudentId == s.Id).Max(e => e.ExamDate)
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time answering my question +1!
What if **LastExamDate** is type Exam not dateTime? I will modify my question

Comment: @Maro No worries!. You'd have to do something like.. `uow.Exams.GetAll().Where(e => e.StudentId == s.Id).OrderByDescending(e => e.ExamDate).FirstOrDefault()` (not tested, but the idea should work). The `OrderByDescending/FirstOrDefault` instead of `Max` change should work for both examples

Comment: Thx i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = (from s in uow.Students.GetAll()
            join e in uow.Exams.GetAll() on s.Id equals e.StudentId
            select new ExamViewModel
            {
                StudentName = s.Name,
                ExamTitle = e.Title,
                ExamDate = e.ExamDate,
                LastExamDate = uow.Exams.GetAll().OrderByDescending(x=> x.ExamDate).First(x=> x.StudentId = s.Id)
            });
```

Comment: `e` is not a collection, it's a row.

Comment: 'Last' will return the last element in the sequence which might not always give you the element having the latest date.

Comment: fixed it. it it ok now?